# The impulse response, $h(t)$, of a system

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, impulse-response, linear-systems, self-study

I have this differential equation 
  $$
    y''(t) + y'(t) + y(t) = x(t) - 3x'(t)
    $$

I found the system response of the system:

$$
        H(f) = \frac{1 - 6\pi fj}{(2\pi fj)^2 +2\pi fj+1}
    $$
which is equivalent to

$$
        H(s) = \frac{1 - 3s}{s^2 +s+1}
$$

My question is: How to find the impulse response? If I factorize the denominator, it's not gonna be pretty. e.g., $s + \frac{1 +\sqrt{-3}}{2}$

Also, what does the following mean?

- Find the output for $t \ge 0$ with initial conditions $y(0) = 1$, $y'(0) = -1$ when the input is $2cos(6t)u(t)$. Identify the zero state, the zero input, the transient, and the steady state responses.

Comment: Consider reviewing material on partial fraction expansion and inverse Laplace transforms.

Comment: i'm still learning what's appropriate and what's not at SE.  this surely looks like homework.  is there a reason that asking the prof or the TA is not possible?

Comment: that said, to find $h(t)$, you *do* have to split $H(s)$ into partial fractions which means you *do* have to factor the denominator which means complex conjugate roots.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson This is not a homework.

Comment: it's the standard stuff from a 2nd or 3rd year EE class.  this has an answer, but i am loathe to just do it for you.  but i'll help you do it, step-by-step.  so, do you know how to do partial fraction expansion?

Comment: There is a `self-study` tag that can be used by those who claim that they are not doing homework problems when in fact they are solving problems that are like typical homework problems, such as the ones at the end of the chapter in a textbook.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I know how to do partial fraction expansion. I thought there is a way to solve this kind of denominator in a pretty way. Thanks though.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I've just added the self-study tag. I'm just preparing myself to an exam, not Signal exam. I think you see that I solved most of the parts, and I'm not asking for an answer. I only need hints. Thanks though!

Comment: @Sultan, solving the denominator means what?  factoring it?  it's what you have to do for partial fraction expansion.  perhaps you can just look up $H(s)$ in a table of Laplace transforms directly, but i think you'll best expand it into two 1st-order partial fractions and then look that up.

Comment: and you know that $\frac{1 +\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is the same as $\frac{1 + j\sqrt{3}}{2}$, right?  and i think you messed up a sign.  ain't one factor $s + \frac{1 + j\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and the other is $s + \frac{1 - j\sqrt{3}}{2}$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson here is my solution:

$$
    H(s)= \frac{1-3s}{(s+\frac{1+j\sqrt{3})}{2})(s+\frac{1-j\sqrt{3})}{2})}= \frac{A}{(s+\frac{1+j\sqrt{3})}{2})}+\frac{B}{(s+\frac{1-j\sqrt{3})}{2})}
$$

$$
    H(s)= \frac{\frac{5}{-2j\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3}{2}}{(s+\frac{1+j\sqrt{3})}{2})}+\frac{ \frac{5}{2j\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3}{2}}{(s+\frac{1-j\sqrt{3})}{2})}
$$

So, the impulse response is: 
$$
    h(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\left [ \frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t) - 3cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t) \right ]
$$

Comment: it looks about right. there's a step in there with $e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)t}$, but if you did your bookkeeping carefully, it's probably right.  and, see, i didn't do it for you. :-)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson these are the two steps before the final one

$$
    h(t)= \left ( \frac{5}{-2j\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3}{2} \right )e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}e^{-(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t}+ \left ( \frac{5}{2j\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3}{2} \right )e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}e^{(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t}
$$

$$
    = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\left [\frac{5}{-2j\sqrt{3}}e^{-(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t}-\frac{3}{2}e^{-(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t}+ \frac{5}{2j\sqrt{3}}e^{(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t}-\frac{3}{2}e^{(\frac{j\sqrt{3}}{2})t} \right ]
$$

And I'm really trying to do my best cuz I want to do it myself :)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson do you know how to do the last part of my question? Find the output with initial conditions? 
I did it, but I want to check my answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate please let me know if you do also know how to do the last part of my question. I did it, but I want to check my answer.

Comment: it's the standard use of Laplace Transform to solve a differential equation.  L.T. takes care of the transient and steady-state response and incorporating the initial conditions.  but i might have to look at a textbook to remind me how to do it the most directly.  this *is* standard 2nd or 3rd year EE stuff.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I know that to identify the zero state response, I would solve it by setting the initial conditions to zero. And to identify the zero input, I would solve it by setting the input to zero and keep the initial conditions. But, how to identify the transient and steady state responses?

Comment: this has to wait for tomorrow.  it's late.

Answer (score 1):

firstly do `partial fraction` for H(s) and then use `transform tables of Laplace` `Transform.` Using inverse laplace and tables you must be able to find impulse response. I think you can use `j^2 instead of -1` and find complex roots for denominator. Then, using transform pairs you will find a `complex solution.`